# How do I force Matplotlib to draw while in the ipdb debugger in Spyder (or any other debugger)?

Tags: python, debugging, matplotlib, pdb, spyder

**EDIT**

Unfortunately, at the moment this is not possible. I found out that it is a [bug in Spyder](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/610). The developers are [still figuring out how to approach this](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/733).

---

### Goal

Visualize data while debugging code (and I want to use Spyder too!).

#### Attempt #1: Run foo.bar from IPython from Spyder

- Create a file named foo.py with the following code:

  ```
    from ipdb import set_trace as st
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    def bar():
        st()
  ```
- While in IPython, type the following:

  ```
    In [4]: import foo

    In [5]: foo.bar()
    --Return--
    None
    > somewhere_over_the_rainbow\foo.py(5)bar()
          3 
          4 def bar():
    ----> 5     st()

    ipdb> plt.plot([1, 2], [3, 4])
    [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x05CA8E90>]
    ipdb> plt.show()
  ```

Plot remains in "frozen" state. If I exit debugger, plot updates. If I try to close the plot, IPython crashes. Obviously both undesirable, and neither lets me see the data while debugging.

#### Attempt #2: Run foo.bar from IPython from command line

- Use same foo.py as in Attempt #1:
- Open IPython from commandline:

  ```
    In [4]: import foo

    In [5]: foo.bar()
    --Return--
    None
    > somewhere_over_the_rainbow\foo.py(5)bar()
          3
          4 def bar():
    ----> 5     st()

    ipdb> plt.plot([1, 2], [3, 4])
    [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x03904070>]
    ipdb> plt.show()
  ```

Program shows plot as I expect. BUT I want to use Spyder.

#### Attempt #3: Run baz.bar from IPython from command line

- Write baz.py:

  ```
    from ipdb import set_trace as st
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    st()
  ```
- Open IPython from commandline:

  ```
    In [4]: import baz
    --Return--
    None
    > somewhere_over_the_rainbow\baz.py(4)<module>()
          2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
          3 
    ----> 4 st()

    ipdb> plt.
  ```

Then Spyder fully freezes.

Any suggestions?

**Note #1**: In my full code, I have many files and many functions, so mashing it all together in one script without functions is not viable.

**Note #2**: Using any matplotlib interactive command (e.g. ion(), interactive(True), etc.) had no effect.

**Note #3**: Spyder version 2.0.12, Python 2.6, matplotlib 1.0.1.

Comment: `C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py:888: UserWarning:  This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect
because the the backend has already been chosen;
matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot,
or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time.

  if warn: warnings.warn(_use_error_msg)`

Comment: `In [3]: matplotlib.get_backend()
Out[3]: 'Qt4Agg'`

Comment: What version of matplotlib do you have?

Comment: Thanks, was able to change it to TkAgg. Same problem happened. `plt.plot()` created the figure, but white content (i.e. nothing written inside); `plt.show()` does nothing; `exit()` caused Spyder to freeze.

Comment: @eryksun let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2543/discussion-between-peter-d-and-eryksun)

Answer (score 16):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Spyder **4.2.0**, released on November 8/2020, supports the ability to work with interactive Matplotlib plots while debugging. That works out of the box, i.e. it doesn't require setting any special option.

For previous versions, the best solution is to use the `pause(n)` command from Matplotlib (where `n` is a number of seconds) after showing the plot on `ipdb`. Here is an example:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow, pause
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(4,5)
imshow(x)
pause(1)
```

Comment: Thanks @Carlos. I've confirmed that this works for `plot()` as well as `imshow()`. This is a near adequate temporary solution. The best way to implement it is to: **(1)** Set the pause time to a really large number. **(2)** When done, hit **Ctrl-C** to escape from the plot and `close()` it. The current shortcoming is that you cannot examine multiple plots simultaneously unless you use `subplot()`

Comment: I think the updated issue is in github now, see here: [Debugging: unable to see plots made with matplotlib · Issue #620 · spyder-ide/spyder](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/620)

Answer (score 5):

I found that you can actually plot in debug mode using Spyder now. It is surprisingly simple.

```
ipdb>pylab.plot(x,y)
ipdb>pylab.show()
```

......

Comment: Please give all version numbers (Spyder, Python, Graphical backend library and version (e.g. Qt)).

Comment: This solution works for me with Spyder 4.1.2, Python 3.7, Qt 5.9.6.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered the `ion()` function when importing `pylab`? This should allow interactive plotting in `pdb`.

```
 import pylab
 import pdb
 pylab.ion()

 tst_xdata = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
 tst_ydata = [1,1,1,1,1,1]

 pylab.plot(tst_xdata,tst_ydata)
 pylab.draw()

 pdb.set_trace()
 for idx in range(3):

     tst_ydata = [elem+2 for elem in tst_ydata]
     pylab.plot(tst_xdata,tst_ydata)
     pylab.draw()

 pylab.show()
```

The above works on my machine (Ubuntu 11.04, Python 2.7, SciPy bersion 0.8.0), even running in Eclipse with PyDev.

Comment: I think OP wanted to run pylab while in the debugging mode, rather than pylab commands already in the .py file.

Comment: It is as @user1914692 said.

Comment: On Ubuntu this issue does not exist. Windows 10 issue.