# matplotlib figures are not displayed when one types imshow(img) in the command prompt in pdb mode

Tags: python, debugging, matplotlib, pdb, spyder

Has anyone encountered this problem using spyder in debug mode (PDB)? It works fine in the interactive mode.

One suggested [solution](https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/detail?id=620) was to use `pause(1)` instead of `show()` after `imshow(img)`.

Is there a better way to see my figures in debug mode? If there was, it would be a real Matlab killer!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To answer my own question. Apparently this is [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080921/how-do-i-force-matplotlib-to-draw-while-in-the-ipdb-debugger-in-spyder-or-any-o?rq=1) and the `pause(1)` is the only way to see plot figures in PDB mode.

The other method is to run the entire program as a script by cutting and pasting it into the command line. This way `show()` can be used instead of `pause(1)`. The advantage to doing it this way, is one can zoom in on the plot. When using `pause(1)` this is only possible during the pause.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2

file_name = 'myimage.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(file_name)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,150,100,apertureSize = 3)

#display image
plt.figure(1)
plt.imshow(edges)
plt.title('edges of image')
plt.show()
```

**Edit:**

I just discovered a nice alternative plotting tool in python called **guiqwt**.

It works with pdb unlike matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
from guiqwt.pyplot import *
figure("simple plot")
subplot(1, 2, 1)
plot(x, np.tanh(x+np.sin(12*x)), "g-", label="Tanh")
legend()
subplot(1, 2, 2)
plot(x, np.sinh(x), "r:", label="SinH")
show()
```

You can get it as part of the included packages in [python(x,y)](https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/wiki/Downloads?tm=2) or you can download it from [here](https://code.google.com/p/guiqwt/)

**Edit2:**

I just found out the latest IDE released by [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) supports matplotlib much better. You can use plt.imshow(img) and don't even have to use plt.show() to display the image in debug mode