# Matplotlib not plotting figure (not responding) on Windows 10 powershell when using "plt.ion()"

Tags: python, matplotlib, emacs, windows-10

I'm working Windows 10 and I have encountered an issue that I don't have on Ubuntu:

From the command line in powershell I run `python myscript.py` where the
scriptp has the following code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2], [1,1])
plt.ion()
plt.show()

import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
pass
```

The following happens:
The plot appears, but very quickly the window gives the "thinking" icon. In the task bar the message is shown "Not responding". The thinking icon appears after having entered something on the command line.

I've tried:

- various matplotlib backends
- ipdb (as opposed to pdb). Now only a little window appears, with the thinking icon and "Not responding" in the task bar.
- Adding `plt.pause(1)` after `plt.show()` (and after `plt.ion()`)
- Writing `plt.pause(1)` *instead* of `plt.show()` --> Some progress, see below:

**Edit**:

Thanks to Sergei Kox I found a work-around for my original question.

However, I usually run powershell inside an inferior emacs shell. I did not mention that, as I thought it was a powershell/windows issue.

Unfortunately, the workaround does not work as well when powershell runs inside emacs. The difference is like this:

*Just Powershell (not inside emacs):*

Using `plt.pause(1)` instead of `plt.show()` the figure becomes responsive and mostly stays responsive! (I also had a few cases where I had to re-type `plt.pause(1)` on the command line). So this is actually a (clunky) work-around, thanks @Sergei Kox.

*Powershell inside emacs inferior shell:*

The figure becomes responsive only during the pause. Once the pause has elapsed, the figure becomes immediately unresponsive. Typing again `plt.pause(1)` the figure becomes responsive again, but only during the pausing ...

... can this be solved!?

Comment: Can you try `plt.pause(1)` after `plt.show()` ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I've tried this a couple of times, also with more than 1 second pause. But to no avail. Things seem to freeze up, including the powershell.

Comment: Can you try `plt.pause(1)` instead of `plt.show()`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51506354/plot-a-function-during-debugging-in-python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23927345/matplotlib-figures-are-not-displayed-when-one-types-imshowimg-in-the-command-p